# Getting large amount of ropsten ether

Tags: ether, testnets, ropsten

I want to get about 150000 ropsten ether for testing. Is there any way to get it? I've seen some faucet websites but they have limitations.

Comment: you don't need this for tests, unless you are doing tests with division operations on the amount. For tests, 1 Wei is enough , you could do 5^18 tests with the amount given to you for free.

Comment: @Nulik Yes that's my reason for that. I want to test my smart contract which has a complicated computations with that number.

Answer (score 1):

It will be very hard, if not impossible, to get 150,000 RETH. Your best bet will be to use a private chain and configure an account to have this amount. You would do this by doing the following:

`ganache-cli --account="<private_key>,<balance>"`

In your case, this would be something like:

`ganache-cli --account="0x3a1076bf45ab87712ad64ccb3b10217737f7faacbf2872e88fdd9a537d8fe266,150000000000000000000000"`

Comment: Sorry but i'm looking a way just for ropsten.

Comment: @zediziza anyone with a 6-digit RETH amount would be able to flood and hang the whole testnet. There's a good reason for not giving away that much test currency - being relatively stable and similar to mainnet in as many ways as possible is the whole point of a public testnet. You can always try mining it though: https://github.com/asseth/ropsten-miner